# RethinkDB filter array, return only matched values

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a table like this

```
{
  dummy: [
     "new val",
     "new val 2",
     "new val 3",
     "other",
  ]   
}
```

want to get only matched values to "new", I am using query like this:

```
r.db('db').table('table')('dummy').filter(function (val) {
 return val.match("^new")
})
```

but its giving error

```
e: Expected type STRING but found ARRAY in
```

what is wrong with query, if I remove .match("^new"), it returns all values

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of why you're getting `Expected type STRING but found ARRAY in` is that the value of the `dummy` field is an array itself, and you cannot apply `match` to arrays.
Despite the `filter` you tried may look confusing, you have to rethink your query a bit: just remap the array to a new `^new`-keyed array, and then just filter its values out in an inner expression.
For example:

```javascript
r.db('db')
    .table('table')
    .getField('dummy')
    .map((array) => array.filter((element) => element.match("^new")))
```

Output:

```
[
    "new val" ,
    "new val 2" ,
    "new val 3"
]
```